# VueJs router-view transitions

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am trying to create some transitions on my router-view components every time I click a new link. The problem is that only one of the fade animations will work. For example, it will fade out, but the new page will appear immediately like normal. Basically I can only have either an enter-active-class or a leave-active-class, but not both at the same time.

```
<template>

    <div class="tom-layout">
        <navBar class="z-depth-0"></navBar>
        <div class="content-layout">
            <transition name="fade">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            navBar: NavBar
        }
    }

</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta');

    body {

        overflow: hidden;

        .content-layout {
            margin-top: -64px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -5;
        }
    }   


.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

.fade-leave {

}

.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am just using [mode](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes): `out-in` it seems to working fine with:

```
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </transition>
```

Please check working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpu356md/).

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the issue.

Another solution I found was to add a transition-delay to .fade-enter-active with the same duration as the transition.

`.fade-enter-active {
 transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
 transition-delay: 0.25s;
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can try dynamic binding for routing transition:

```
<router-view :transition="$route.transition">
And set the data of transition from your route data

router.map({
  '/About': {
    component: { ... },
    transition: 'slide'
  }
})
```

Comment: `router.map` has been replaced with array literals. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html#router-map-replaced